# Best way to upload a large data frame from R to Big Query?

Tags: r, google-bigquery

In my case, bq_table_upload() does not work since the file is 5G. Exporting to CSV and uploading through the BQ web UI also fails because of size. I think the code below used to be how I did this, but authentication through gar_auth() via the browser no longer works for me:

```
library(googleCloudStorageR)
library(bigrquery)
library(googleAuthR)

gcs_global_bucket("XXXXXXXXX")

## custom upload function to ignore quotes and column headers
f <- function(input, output) {
  write.table(input, sep = ",", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, 
              quote = FALSE, file = output, qmethod = "double")}

## upload files to Google Cloud Storage
gcs_upload(mtcars, name = "mtcars_test1.csv", object_function = f)

## create the schema of the files you just uploaded
user_schema <- schema_fields(mtcars)

## load files from Google Cloud Storage into BigQuery
bqr_upload_data(projectId = "your-project", 
                datasetId = "test", 
                tableId = "from_gcs_mtcars", 
                upload_data = c("gs://XXXXX/mtcars_test1.csv")
                schema = user_schema)
```

Is there any workaround?

---

This is the error this produces:

```
> gcs_upload(mtcars, name = "mtcars_test1.csv", object_function = f)
2020-06-30 11:49:37 -- File size detected as 1.2 Kb
2020-06-30 11:49:37> No authorization yet in this session!
2020-06-30 11:49:37> NOTE: a  .httr-oauth  file exists in current working directory.
 Run authentication function to use the credentials cached for this session.
Error: Invalid token
```

Then I tried to authenticate with

```
gar_auth()
```

which launches a Chrome browser window where I was usually able to authenticate by picking the right Google profile, but now get "Error 400: invalid_request Missing required parameter: client_id".

Comment: Did you try doing partial insert, say 100000 rows at a time? Use bq_table_upload for the first iteration, then use bq_table_patch to insert the other rows in the loop.

Comment: @BrunoTremblay I can definitely use bq_table_upload() for small dataframes, but I guess I would rather not loop if a gcs solution exists.

Comment: The correct pattern to use is export -> upload to GCS -> import to BigQuery (via API). What exactly not working in that pipeline?

Comment: @GrahamPolley I added the errors that I am getting. I believe I am following your chain, but am unable to authenticate to do the upload step.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`gcs_auth()`](http://code.markedmondson.me/googleCloudStorageR/reference/gcs_auth.html) to authenticate your session for upload or [see website on setting up authentication on library startup](http://code.markedmondson.me/googleCloudStorageR/articles/googleCloudStorageR.html#configuring-your-own-google-project)